# Travelling US with mother B1/B2 and myself L2

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, family

I am traveling with my mother to New York. She has B1/B2 Visa and I have L2 Visa. Can we go together as a family at POE immigration counter OR we may have to split lanes since the visa is different.

Answer (score 4):

New York airports typically have two lines for those who are not US citizens or permanent residents: one for A and G visas, and one for everyone else, so both of you should go to that line anyway.  Furthermore, the practice of Customs and Border Protection immigration inspectors is to process groups of travelers together, so even if you find a situation in the future where you should nominally go to different lines you can nonetheless pick one of them and use it together.